# How to code An Azure function to receive data from a web portal?

Tags: c#, azure-functions

How to code An Azure function to receive data from a web portal(Front end) like **Patient name, Age, Sex** etc and also send back the data when ever it is requested from the front end

Using Visual Studio i have created the Azure function, *HTTP trigger*

Comment: _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_

Comment: I changed your title to make it read like a `question` rather than it being a statement of something

Comment: You can treat http trigger Azure functions similar to traditional APIs. Simply pass the parameters (front end or any where) in request body and consume them in azure function. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook#trigger---c-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overall idea is to use HttpTrigger of Azure function , which intern can be triggered from Web app by posting http request and later can be de-crypt at function end.

The following example shows a C# function that looks for a name parameter either in the query string or the body of the HTTP request. Notice that the return value is used for the output binding, but a return value attribute isn't required.

```
[FunctionName("HttpTriggerCSharp")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] 
    HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    string name = req.Query["name"];

    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
    name = name ?? data?.name;

    return name != null
        ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}")
        : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
}
```

Here is the binding for the same:

```
{
    "disabled": false,
    "bindings": [
        {
            "authLevel": "function",
            "name": "req",
            "type": "httpTrigger",
            "direction": "in",
            "methods": [
                "get",
                "post"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "$return",
            "type": "http",
            "direction": "out"
        }
    ]
}
```

Also , Here's C# script code that binds to HttpRequest:

```
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    string name = req.Query["name"];

    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
    name = name ?? data?.name;

    return name != null
        ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}")
        : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
}
```

You can take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook#trigger---c-example) link for further reference.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank You Mohit Verma You really solve my challenges for me, I am Very grateful.. Cheers